# Automatically fade audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, fadein, fadeout

I have a working script that plays a different audio every 45 minutes.

The audio files change on a daily basis, so i cant manually fade them in/out in Audacity.

In the script, i have the following line:

```
ffplay -i /home/user/Ringtone1.mp3 -ss 00:00:7 -t 20 -nodisp -autoexit
```

But every time, the audio cuts abruptly after 20 seconds, which isn't very ear-pleasing.

I want to make the audio fade in from 0 to max in 5 seconds and then fade out from max to 0 in 5 seconds (at the end of the 20 seconds).

How can i do that?